# Multiple reacts on the same ip

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker

I have four react-app, I want to serve them on the same domain, but with different domains:

- example.com
- a.example.com
- b.example.com
- c.example.com

How can I render them on the same IP? Is it correct to create a docker to serve them as microservices and then manage their ports with nginx/apache?

Comment: Yes that's a great way to get started. You can check out more info here: https://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker/

Comment: I’d probably run Webpack to generate static files from them, but then, yes, you need something like Apache or Nginx to serve them on different domains.